# Best terminal for macos

Tags: mac, terminal, shell

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What's your favorite app alternative for Mac OS X's Terminal.app?](https://superuser.com/questions/123839/whats-your-favorite-app-alternative-for-mac-os-xs-terminal-app)
>   [Alternative terminal emulators for OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/146121/alternative-terminal-emulators-for-os-x)

Are there any alternatives for Terminal.app.

Maby with good autocompletion, color schemes, maybe bundles etc.

Comment: [or this one](http://superuser.com/questions/146121/alternative-terminal-emulators-for-os-x).

Comment: Also see [here](http://superuser.com/questions/232583/color-coding-mac-terminal/232828#232828).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default terminal for mac has color schemes and auto completion.

Two alternatives are [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/) and [Terminator](http://software.jessies.org/terminator/).

Answer (score 1):

I would definitly recommend [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/). It is a really good Terminal Application, featuring a nice fullscreen mode, good customizability. I'm a Ruby/Rails Programmer, and Terminal.app didn't highlight the Rake Tasks and so on for me. iTerm does with no additional configuration.